# Create an instance of Managed/ Flexible Virtual machine in google app engine and then connect it with the project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I have a project on google app engine for which I am using google cloud sql database. I would like to install a NoSql database on the flexible/ Managed VM and mirgrate my data from cloud sql to the database on Managed VM. 
I would like to know:

1. How to create an Instance of Managed VM?
2. How to connect an existing app engine project with the Managed VM instance?

Comment: Not sure you understand what is Managed VM. You shouldn't store anything on such machines, it must be stateless. Same as standard App Engine VM.

You need Compute Engine or Container Engine.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Igor. Then how can I create a mongoDB database and connect it to my app engine project. I don't want to look after the management of the database size allocation etc. Hence, I thought I can use managed VM for it.

Comment: try Container Engine then